How to remove old elastomeric terrace isolation to apply new one?
We want to make terrace isolation but we want to smoth the surface by removing those old elastic layers.
Any way how to remove and smoth the surface before applying elastomeric sealant to the terrace?
https://imgur.com/a/jYHqqFy
